# Triple monitor + dedicated CUDA card .. what are my options?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, integrated-graphics, intel-graphics, cuda

I have the following -
Core i7 3770 (Ivybridge - Supports 3 independent displays .. apparently)
GA-B75-D3H (B75 Chipset - Supports 3 independent displays .. apparently .. has VGA,HDMI,DVI)
GTX 650 (Kepler GPU - Supports 3 independent displays - 2 DVI and 1 mini HDMI)

What I want is a triple monitor setup, with the CPU driving the 3 displays and the GPU as a dedicated CUDA card. If I run the display with the GPU, it supports my 3 monitors fine (All 3 are identical and same resolution by the way .. so hopefully no issues with different PLLs?)

However, if I use the "Init graphics IGD" as opposed to "PCX" the system boots fine but Windows doesn't recognize the Intel HD4000 (in the Core i7) at all and shows me a stock 800x600 resolution and the Intel Hardware identification utility doesn't even run.

Any suggestions on how I can proceed? I don't want to buy a second nVidia card, since I only have 1 x16 PCI-e port (the other is also x16 but x4 lanes).

What exactly are the steps I should be following to run 3 monitors through my CPU and use the GPU for CUDA only? (Let's solve this first on Windows and then worry about Linux...)

Comment: 1) Do the three displays run fine if you remove the CUDA card? (Just as a test to verify that it can work. I know you already wrote that the CPU and board *should* support it; but do test this to make sure this works as expected.)      2) A second second nVidia card (or a second card from another brand) should work fine. It is a waste of resources since I do not think you need it, but it should work fine. Even in an x4 wired slot. (You loose around 5% performance, but even a mid-level dedicated card in a x4 slot should be faster then the one build into the CPU).

Answer (score 0):

Keep the settings on your motherboard so that it works with the Intel IGD as primary with your 3x monitor plugged in.Like you told us it was working earlier.

It seams the option your referring to: Is to disable your on-board graphic, or to put the Nvidia as primary, Both which you don't want to do in your setup.

1. Have your Nvidia plugged in and Setup it's PCI-E Slot to 16x in your bios. 
   Something like , 16x1x1x or 16x4x4 not 8x4x4, so that the first number is 16x.
2. You may need to put the port in compatibility mode to PCI-E:2.0 instead of PCI-E:3.0
3. Boot then Install your Nvidia Driver, then install Cuda.
4. if in Device manager the Nvidia card shows up, your card should be up and ready to run.

   - You Can, Just to test if the Nvidia is working, un-plug your 3rd monitor from your motherboard and plug it in the Nvidia Card. Then in Windows ­> Screen resolution > Detect > Select the monitor > Extend my desktop on this monitor.
   - If something is showing from the Monitor off the Nvidia card it means it's all good. Plug back the Monitor in the motherboard. Screen resolution > Detect > Select the monitor > Extend my desktop on this monitor.
   - You can try alternatively and see if the Nvidia Card is doing it job, By processing a Work Unit From Folding @ home.